# How to copy an object from one model to another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Each user has **many** *albums*, and each album has its **many** *photos*. And each user has *one set* **background image** to hold its many images. Similarly, a user has *one set* of **profile picture** to hold its many images.

These are my models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    permanent_address = models.TextField()
    temporary_address = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ForeignKey(ProfilePicture)
    background_pic = models.ForeignKey(BackgroundImage)


class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=3)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class BackgroundImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Eg: I tried doing this:  to let the user copy **one** *image* from **ProfilePicture** to **Background Image**, but didn't work:

```
# Get the user
>>>m = User.objects.get(username='m')

# Get its set of Profile pictures
>>>m_pro_set = m.profilepicture_set.all()
>>>m_pro_set
[<ProfilePicture: pro_mik>]

# Get its set of Background images
>>>m_back_set = m.backgroundimage_set.all()
>>>m_back_set
[<BackgroundImage: bg_mik>]

# Get an image object from Profile picture of the user
>>>m_pro_1 = m.profilepicture_set.get(id=2)
>>>m_pro_1
<ProfilePicture: pro_mik>

# Get an image object from Background image of the user
>>>m_back_1 = m.backgroundimage_set.get(id=2)
>>>m_back_1
<BackgroundImage: bg_mik>

# So, I tried to copy one image from BackgroundImage of a user to ProfilePicture

>>>m_pro_set.objects.create(m_back_1)

    File "<console>", line 1, object has attribute 'objects'
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

So my question is, how to copy an objects from one model to another? Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to copy the properties of one object to another object.  `create` is used when you want to create a new instance, not when you want to update a specific instance.

```
m_pro = m_pro_set[0] # m_pro_set is a list and need to get the specific instance
m_pro.image = m_back_1.image
m_pro.caption = m_back_1.caption
m_pro.pub_date = m_back_1.pub_date
m_pro.save()
```

Alternatively you can create a method on `ProfilePicture` if this is a common operation to contain this functionality.

```
class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def update(self, bg_img):
        self.image = bg_img.image
        self.caption = bg_img.caption
        self.pub_date = bg_img.pub_date
        self.save()
```

So you would just need to call `m_pro_1.update(m_back_1)` if we wanted to make `m_pro_1` have the same properties as `m_back_1`

Also, if you wanted to create a new instance, I'd suggest using a `classmethod` like the following

```
class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def create_from_bg(cls, bg_img):
        img = cls(user=bg_img.user, image=bg_img.image, caption=bg_img.caption, pub_date=bg_img.pub_date)
        img.save()
        return img

    @classmethod
    def create_from_photo(cls, photo):
        img = cls(user=photo.album.user, image=photo.image, caption=photo.caption, pub_date=photo.pub_date)
        img.save()
        return img
```

This creates a new `ProfilePicture` and is used: `profile_pic = ProfilePicture.create_from_bg(m_back_1)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried the way its here. But I guess you got me wrong. What I want is to copy an image from one model and then create it in another model, but to leave the original image as it is. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: Use the classmethod approach.  It's a factory function to generate a new object.  You can create one for each of your types (referring to your comment on the other answer).

Comment: Oh! Am sorry. I didn't looked at it properly. I think its easier. But how do I create a new instance from model **Photo** to ProfilePic or to BackgroundImage. Is it the same procedure?

Comment: I added something to my answer to show you how that might look.  Basically, you can use anything as your parameter as long as you can define the properties of your model from that.

Comment: Did this answer your question or do you need further clarification on something?

Comment: Sorry, I was so busy. And thank you so very much! Now I know about classmethod too! Just, one more question though... When I copy an image, I don't think that it really copies the `image file`, but just the `path of the image`. How do I deal with it. Suppose the user deletes the image, the other file will also be deleted right? Please correct me if I am wrong. And thank you again! :)

Comment: Have you tried it?  If I recall correctly, each new record will create a different filepath even if the filename you specify is the same.  Django doesn't overwrite files if they have the same name.

Comment: Umh... I dont think so... Supppse, I have two image, one is profile pic and the other is background image. Now if I copy an image from background image into profile pic pic, i should have 3 photos. But still, there's only two photo in the folder. M i missing something....?

Comment: Try changing image.name to something unique and see if there is another file.

Comment: Hi! So, I changed the caption to `caption=bg_img.caption+'_copy'`. And then I copied the image. I get an image with different caption too. But, no actual file has been copied. Just the same `file path` with different `caption`.